# In my android app, a folder named com appeared in my app with only one MANIFEST.MF file in it. I don't know how it appeared

Tags: android, apk

A folder named "com" appeared in my app file, with only one MANIFEST.MF file in it. I don't know how it appeared.

can anyone tell me why? i will appreciate it if anyone could help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcERG.png)

Comment: Mybe some library added it there during build time

Comment: Are you using Android view of folders?, there it will show it's proper location.